# How to change or replace text under div, row with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to change or replace text under div, tag, row with JS. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div .row .col-sm-4").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == "Registrant ID:") {
      $(this).text().replace("Registrant Number:");
    }
  });
});
```

HTML Code Here :

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">Registrant ID:</div>

</div>
```

I am using javascript here, it seems to have no effect.

Comment: It would be of more help to see your HTML, although you're not using the value returned from `replace()` which is an issue in itself, and you're not supplying a replacement value to that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.html()` instead of `.text().replace()` and change div selector.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".col-sm-4").each(function() {
   if ($(this).text() == "Registrant ID:") {
     $(this).html("Registrant Number:");
   }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-4">Registrant ID:</div>

   </div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/352cy4j5/)

Answer (score 0):

You are just replacing and not setting to it and corrected your selector  a bit, there should not be any space between `div` and `.row`

```
if ($(this).text() == "Registrant ID:") {
$(this).text().replace("Registrant Number:");
}
```

Should be

```
if ($(this).text() == "Registrant ID:") {
  $(this).text("Registrant Number:");
}
```

---

```js
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $("div.row .col-sm-4").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == "Registrant ID:") {
      $(this).text("Registrant Number:");
    }
  });
});

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">Registrant ID:</div>
  <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" name="domainfield[0][1]" value="" size="20" class="form-control input-250 input-inline"> *</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.text()` instead of `.text().replace()`, check snippet below

```js
$(".row .col-sm-4").each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == "Registrant ID:") {
    $(this).text("Registrant Number:");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">Registrant ID:</div>
  <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" name="domainfield[0][1]" value="" size="20" class="form-control input-250 input-inline"> *</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var a = $(".row .col-sm-4").text();
    if (a == "Registrant ID:") {
      $(".row .col-sm-4").text("Registrant Number:");
    }
});
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">Registrant ID:</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("div.row .col-sm-4").each(function() {    
      if ($(this).text() == "Registrant ID:") {
        $(this).text("Registrant Number:");
      }
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">Registrant ID:</div>

</div>
```